# Flutter Gridview builder not working with column

Tags: gridview, material-design, flutter, multiple-columns

Here are my file and the Gridview not working it's showing me an only error...

I am using multiple children for the column and needed to use gridview builder here.

Also, I tried using Stack and removed the column and it worked but in that case, I need to use lots of padding for every section and that worthless.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBarComponent(),
    drawer: new Drawer(child: DrawerList()),
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.02),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Form(
                    key: formKey,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 280.0,
                      height: 40.0,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        onSaved: (val) => keyword = val,
                        validator: this._validateKeyword,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Search Product",
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          filled: true,
                          contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  ButtonTheme(

                    minWidth: 6.0,
                    height: 40.0,

                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.9),

                      onPressed: _search,
                      child: Icon(Icons.search,color:Colors.white,size: 26.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0)),
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: 40.0,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.assignment_turned_in,color: Colors.greenAccent,),

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0,right: 8.0),
                    child: Text("SEARCH RESULT",style: TextStyle(fontSize:14.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0)),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    height: 24.0,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      onPressed:()=>print("a"),
                      child: new Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6.0),
                            child: Icon(Icons.filter,size: 16.0,),
                          ),
                          Text('FILTER',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0)),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    height: 24.0,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed:()=>print("a"),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                      child: new Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6.0),
                            child: Text('SORT BY',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),),
                          ),
                          Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,size: 16.0,),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            Expanded(
                child: new GridView.builder(

                  itemCount: 10,
                  gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {



                    return Container(
                      child: Card(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                              child: Image.asset('images/product-1.png',width: 100.0),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.02),
                              height: 55.0,
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: Text("It is a long established fact that a readerIt is a long established fact that a reader.",
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:8.0,left: 4.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Text("\$57 ",style: TextStyle(fontSize:12.0,color: Colors.red,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                        Text(" \$57",style: TextStyle(fontSize:12.0,decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough),),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0),
                                          child: ButtonTheme(

                                            minWidth: 8.0,
                                            height: 8.0,

                                            child: RaisedButton(
                                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),

                                              onPressed: null,
                                              child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart,size: 18.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),

                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.0),
                                          child: ButtonTheme(

                                            minWidth: 8.0,
                                            height: 8.0,

                                            child: RaisedButton(
                                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.9),

                                              onPressed: null,
                                              child: Icon(Icons.favorite,size: 18.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),


                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),

                            ),



                          ],

                        ),
                      ),
                    );



                  },
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
    )
);
```

}

Comment: Please include the error you get

Comment: I faced this issue last week and solved by using expanded widget.looks like you used it and as I checked the code on my device, it worked just fine. would you add the error you get, please?

Comment: your code is working fine. can you add errors ??

Answer (score 2):

I've tried your code snippet and the only error that I got was UI overflow errors from the widgets.

[image: Demo UI Overflow]

One way to solve this issue is by using `Expanded` widget on the Column's children widget. It'll look something similar to this.

```dart
Container(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: Text(),
      ),
      Expanded(
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(),
            Text(),
            Button(),
            Button(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

With that added, the ListView items will look like this.

[image: Demo Expanded]